# Using regular expression to extract a text

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

x  = "[['Glass Battery Hydrometer'], ['RS Stock No.', '196-8187'], ['Mfr. Part No.'], ['Brand', 'RS Pro'], ['Compare']]"

How to use regular expression in python to extract "['RS Stock No.', '196-8187']" this particular portion from the string

Also once that particular string is extracted I need to extract '196-8187' this value from it.

Comment: `re.findall(...)[1]`

Comment: Regex is about matching patterns. You haven't described the pattern you want to match. Do you see the problem with this? You have to tell us _why_ `['RS Stock No.', '196-8187']` should be extracted or we can't help you.

Comment: I have a column consisting of similar strings. I want to form a new column consisting of 'RS Stock no' alone

Answer (score 0):

About so:

```
^\[\[.*\]\, \[('.*','(.*)')\].*$
```